# Warning when installing simple packages in R studio

Tags: r

I try to make a simple package in R with one function, namely the built in "hello"

When I install the package i get a warning that the package is not available for R version 4.0.0) - this error i get for all my packages.

What is going on?? any suggestions?

Comment: Help us help you: Provide a [mcve]. _How_ did you attempt to install your custom package? I am assuming with a simple `install.packages("your_package")`. If you consult `help("install.packages")`, you'll see that without setting `repos = NULL`, it's going to look for your package in the CRAN repos, where it is certainly not available. But, it's hard to say for certain unless you [edit] your question to show exactly how you went about trying to install your package.

Comment: install.packages("TEST", lib="h:/r_packages")

Comment: Again, you should consult `help("install.packages")`. There you'll see that `lib` tells R where to install the packages to, while `repos` tells R where to get the packages from. You want to set `repos = NULL`, and provide the full or relative path to your custom package as a character vector (of length one) for the `pkgs` argument

Comment: I have a new computer and downloaded R and R studio. I think it is reasonable to expect that the setup is straight forward, but it isn't. I get ERROR on ERROR on this, and i have not even written any code. Ofcourse the answer is in some manual, but that is really not any help. Obviously there are some default setting i am not aware of, but makes it impossible to use R and Rstudio. If the best answer is "look in the manual", well then its bad luck for me

Comment: I'm generally not a fan of answers that just say "read the manual" for this reason, because they are not very beginner-friendly. At the same time, however, you haven't really given us much to go on in your posted question. You need to give more information about what you did (and in this case, probably why you thought it would work when doing it that way), and what you instead expect to get any meaningful help. In honesty, it sounds like what you probably need is a full beginner-friendly primer using R, using RStudio, and making packages, probably in that order. Learning a programming (1/2)

Comment: language is not a "pick it up in an afternoon" type undertaking (or, at least, it wasn't for me). It will take work and probably quite a bit of reading. Here are some resources that are more beginner-friendly than "the manual": [R for Beginners](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Paradis-rdebuts_en.pdf), [RStudio's learning page](https://education.rstudio.com/learn/beginner/), [Hadley's Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/), [Karl Broman's R packages primer](https://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/), and [Hadley's R Packages book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/). All these are free to read online. (2/2)

Comment: I agree with your comments.. it just so bloody frustrating.. i am not a beginner.. i have spend thousand of hours coding, and here i am, with nothing working on second week... not even the most simple thing, in a completly new installation....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218701/discussion-between-duckmayr-and-soren-stilling-christensen).